# Ending of Silent Hill: Downpour

Tags: silent-hill-downpour

Is there just a single ending or are there different endings in Silent Hill: Downpour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game has **6 possible endings**, but only 5 are available on the first playthrough. The ending obtained depends on 3 factors.

1. One factor is the "**moral score**", increased or decreased depending on the moral choices made during gameplay, and how many monsters the player has killed. A positive score can be obtained when Murphy makes positive moral choices, and by sparing the lives of monsters. A negative score is accumulated when Murphy makes poor moral choices, and when he kills monsters, rather then incapacitating or ignoring them.
2. The second factor is **the decision regarding Anne's fate** in the game's finale.
3. The third consists of **the player surviving the finale**, since dying only rewards the player with the **Reversal** ending.

After the game's completion a new sidequest is added, **Digging Up the Past**, and completing this sidequest it rewards the player with the **Surprise** ending. Akin to Silent Hill 4: The Room, Downpour does not have a UFO Ending.

### Endings

**Ending A - Forgiveness:**
You'll obtain this ending by having good karma (choose to help when given the option) and sparing the character at the end.

**Ending B - Truth and Justice:**
You'll receive this ending if you killed too many enemies, even if you had good karma otherwise by choosing to help the two other characters early on.

**Ending C - Full Circle:**
Achieve this ending by having good karma (choose to help when given the option) but killing the character at the end.

**Ending D - Execution:**
This ending is achieved by having bad karma (do not choose to help when given the option) and by killing the character at the end.

**Ending E - Surprise:**
This ending is achieved by completing the Digging Up the Past side quest on your second play through.

**Ending F - Reversal:**
Achieve this ending by dying at the end. Anna will wake up from a dream and be inside a cell, and Murphy will be a prison guard.

<sub>Resources:

- [Silent Hill Wikia](http://silenthill.wikia.com/wiki/Silent_Hill:_Downpour)
- [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/silent-hill-downpour/Endings)</sub>

The video including all ending cutscenes: